# What's a quick way to cycle through every cell in a worksheet

Tags: arrays, excel, loops, for-loop, range

I'm comparing columns A of two worksheets and if they match, the value in the second column of sheet 1 is being added to the sum total in the second column of sheet 2

[image: Sheet1]
[image: Sheet2]

Sheet1 and Sheet2 respectively
Sheet 2 column B is empty before the code below is run.

```
Function TotalNames()

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

For i = 1 To 4

    For j = 1 To 8

        If sht1.Cells(j, 1).Value = sht2.Cells(i, 1).Value Then

            sht2.Cells(i, 2).Value = sht2.Cells(i, 2).Value + sht1.Cells(j, 2).Value

        End If

    Next j

Next i

End Function
```

I'm working on a project which compares many columns and rows between these two sheets and it can take a long time to process. I've also turned screen updating off and calculations to manual but was hoping this can be sped up with arrays or ranges but am struggling where to start.

Comment: If the code works, then this question may be more appropriate over on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: To be clear, you don't actually need to loop through every cell in a worksheet, just a range correct?

Comment: Why vba? This could easily be done with a pivot table or SUMIF() formula.

Comment: @BruceWayne well it needs to look at each cell and evaluate it against the other sheet. Could probably done with a range but not sure how

Comment: @ScottCraner This is a very simplified version of what I'm trying to solve. Not each row is a running total. There are other comparisons being made. What's important is the speed with which it can go through each row and column and make these comparisons.

Comment: Load every thing into variant arrays and loop them not the cells.  It will speed it up.

Comment: @Scott Craner Thanks. I will look into using variant arrays

Comment: I know this isn't VBA, but have you considered just using a pivot table or using the SUMIF(...) formula?